# Angular 4 Http missing response text when status code = 400

Tags: angular, angular-http

I'm using Angular Http like this:

```
this.http
    .post(url, JSON.stringify(data), this.createOptions())
    .subscribe(response => {
             ... do something
        }, error => {
            if (error.status === 400){
                ...do something
            }
            else if (error.status === 500) {
                ...do something else                                    
            }
        }),
    }
```

The problema is that when I get a `400` error code, the server returns me the error message as a `string` in the body. But this seems to disappear when the response goes to the `catch` block. The server response is arriving correctly, I'm testing it with Postman, but in angular, the body is replaced with something else. If I use `error.text()` I get this, instead of the error message:

```
"_body": {
    "__zone_symbol__currentTask": {
        "type": "microTask",
        "state": "notScheduled",
        "source": "Promise.then",
        "zone": "angular",
        "invoke": "invoke()function () {_numberOfNestedTaskFrames++; try { self.runCount++; return self.zone.runTask(self, this, arguments);\n                    }\n                finally {\n                    if (_numberOfNestedTaskFrames == 1) {\n                        drainMicroTaskQueue();\n                    }\n                    
_numberOfNestedTaskFrames--;\n                }\n            }",
        "cancelFn": null,
        "runCount": 0,
        "callback": "callback()function () {\n            try {\n                resolvePromise(chainPromise, true, zone.run(delegate, undefined, 
[promise[symbolValue]]));\n            }\n            catch (error) {\n                resolvePromise(chainPromise, false, error);\n            }\n        }"
    }
},
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just reread your question and realized my answer is completely unhelpful, sorry. However, while testing my answer I did run into your problem. I got that wierd `_body` object anytime my api didn't respond for whatever reason like hit an endpoint that didn't exist

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the `.map()`, please try the below:

```
this.http.post(url, data, this.createOptions())
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe((response: any) => {
        ... do something
      }, (error: any) => {
        if (error.status === 400){
          ...do something
        } else if (error.status === 500) {
          ...do something else                                    
        }
      }
    );
```

You will also need to import `Response` like so:

```
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: The `map` operator will only work if the response code is `200`, which is not related to my question, since my problem is accessing the original body contents when the request falls on the error path

Comment: No. You could add a `.catch()` after the `.map()` to catch errors if you like, but using just the `.map()` will work. You can just catch the error in the `(error: any)`. The `.map()` is needed

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this, when the rxjs creates the error object it attaches the original response as a property you can access. So you can do something like...

```
(err) => err._body
```

just tested this, `_body` will be a string value of the response text

Comment: Yes, the _body property exists, but it contains that weird json object instead of the response text.